# Why do people glow sometimes?

Tags: spiral-knights

Sometimes, I see people glow for a few seconds:

[image]

What is that, what does it mean and how can I do it?

Comment: do they stop glowing after an attack?  If I remember from my brief playing of this game during the steam holiday achievement thing, it looks like he's charging up an attack.

Comment: @yx. It doesn't *seem* to be tied to attacks, but it lasts a few seconds and goes away.

Comment: well in that case that exhausts my minute knowledge about this game :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, Spiral Knights changed the charge up animation for weapons. (It used to be most more obvious what was going on)

This glow appears when you have a fully charged attack, which you can do by holding the attack button down.

The exact nature of the charge attack depends on the weapon you are using.

Comment: Huh.  Turns out yx was right after all.